# How to use InvokeHttp to Rest Api(POST)

Tags: rest, api, apache-nifi

Good Morning everyone
So I need to invoke a POST REST API using Apache Nifi so I configured it:
[image: nifi project structure]
[image: InvokeHttp configuration for POST]
[image: InvokeHttp configuration for POST]
and I need to know if it is working or no! How can I do it?
Is my configuration is right or not?
Thank you

Comment: Do you get errors when you try this? What is happening? The configuration seems OK but if you see errors then we can see what can be changed.

Comment: @WinnieDaPooh I don't see anything actually! I want to know if it is working or not! I've tested it using `petstore.swagger.io` but it looks like nothing happening! 
Is there is any way or any processor that shows me the response of this call??

Comment: On second look, your "Put Response Body in Attribute" is incorrect. This is the name of the attribute that will take the response that is received from the API call

Comment: Also, you don't have to configure "SSL Context Service" since the URL you are trying to hit is not ssl enabled.

Comment: Your flowfile content will be your BODY. which means, what you have under "Put Response Body in Attribute" should infacet be your flowfile content

Comment: @WinnieDaPooh look at the editing: all I want is to get the response of InvokeHttp! is it possible in this way ? is there is any modification? I'm just a beginner in apache NiFi and all I want is to call a rest API and apply it on a specific app !

Comment: Like I already mentioned, you don't need the `SSL Context Service` because the webservice you are trying hit is HTTP and not HTTPS. And you need something like a `GenerateFlowFile` that can act as a trigger for your "InvokeHTTP".

Comment: @WinnieDaPooh actually it really works :D! like magic ! you can add it like an answer and thank you very much

Comment: Glad to know it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `SSL Context Service` because the service you are trying to call is not SSL enabled. So remove that.

Your `Put Response Body in Attribute` is incorrect. This is the name of the attribute that will hold the response that is received from the API call.

You need a trigger processor like `GenerateFlowFile` to activate your `InvokeHTTP`.

Feel free to edit my answer if you did more to fix your issue so we could correctly document it here.